# Cannot get back from wifi configuration page

Tags: android, system, wifi

I develop a very simple application that connects to a wifi network and then does some stuff.

The idea is that i open the wifi configuration page to select a wifi network.

Until here I'm doing fine But then when i press the back button to go back to my application it reloads the wifi configuration page.

Here is my code:

```
public class SetHttp extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.WebcamView.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_http);
        WifiManager mWifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(!mWifi.isWifiEnabled()){
            mWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }
        sendIntent();
    }

    protected void sendIntent(){
        Intent enwifi = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(enwifi, 3);
    }

    public void sendHttp(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebPage.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
         startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I have tried to create the onStart, onRestart... methods but the application crashes.

Any ideas ? Should Use startActivityForResult and onActivity Result and what should i write in on ActivityResult ??

Thank you very much!!

I have tried some things but none of them is working. Here is my code:

```
public class SetHttp extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.WebcamView.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_http);
    WifiManager mWifi = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if(!mWifi.isWifiEnabled()){
        mWifi.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    //sendIntent();
}
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //sendIntent();
}
protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    //sendIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_http);
}
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_http);
}
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}
protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_http);
    sendIntent();
}

protected void sendIntent(){
    Intent enwifi = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(enwifi);
}

public void sendHttp(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebPage.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`sendIntent();` will always be called. It is the last statement in `onCreate()`. If you want to call it only once, consider changing its place.

NinjaEdit: You don't have (or at least not shown, I hope?) `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`. I am not sure if you can return any result with from there (you cannot if you open the GPS settings for sure), so if you cannot, I suggest you to use flags (if first time, call the method, when calling turn the flag, and upon returning decide what to do).

Comment: Thank you for your answerOk I get the first comment so where do you sugest i put it so it does its job for one time and then i can return to my application?

Comment: Just make a flag connected=false. Instead of sendIntent(); make it 
    if(!connected) {        
        sendIntent();
    }

In onRestart() you can add this part, but make sure it is called only once (add another flag for firstRun for example), and make it true in onCreate().
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (ni.isConnected()) {
        connected=true;
    }
So now when you come back you should not have it starting again.

Comment: Sorry about bad formatting, guess comments are not that good with code. Ask once again if I failed to explain it.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I do not really understand where to put all those things you said. I also have another question. I know that when an activity calls another then when you press the back button from the new activity it should take you to the previous activity. Lets say that I put the sendIntent() to the onStart(). Then it should open the first time I run the application choose my wifi network and then when I click back It takes me to my app. Where is the mistake in this thought??

Comment: That is why I told you to create another flag. In onStart you cannot have the flag changed, so you will check for the default option to be false, for example. In onCreate you change the flag, so when you go to the Wi-Fi settings, and come back, the flag will allow onStart's check method to run. Basically you won't let it go the first time, but allow it any subsequent time. If you do not want it to be any subsequent time after that, you can always change the flag when you come back from the wi-fi settings window.